# promoted links customization

Tags: promoted-links

I am trying to customize promoted links in SP2013 using css but I am not able to do that ... the transparent block doesn't move after giving top & width parameters , am I missing something ? I just want same behavior with increase height & width of the box.

Comment: The overlay animation is controlled through JavaScript, so if you set a `top` value for it the animation is defeated.  See my answer here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/169304/8992 and this other question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/108839/8992

Answer (score 0):

Add a script editor web part and paste the css provided here:
http://www.underthefleece.co.uk/2015/02/change-size-of-promoted-links-in.html

Comment: the animation doesn't work properly , it is useful for shrinking not to enlarge.