# Overlay Promoted Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, promoted-links

I'm trying to lower the overlay, like how this question [described](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169303/lower-the-level-of-the-overlay-before-hover-of-promoted-links-web-part). I just don't understand on how to edit the jquery/js from the [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108839/customize-promoted-links-tiles-view-in-sharepoint-2013) given.

```
$v_2.SetAttribute(2, this.$8_0 ? 0 : this.$N_0);
```

I tried switching 0 into 100px or even 100, but the overlay goes back to the original spot after I hover it. I just want the overlay to return to the set position. So if I set 'top' as 200px, the overlay should go back at 200px, instead of the 100px original position.

I assume that this is what I'm supposed to do to the new function.

```
function OverridePromoAnimation(){
    SP.UI.TileView.TileViewRenderer.Tile.prototype.$o_0= function () {

         //insert the original method, but edit this line
         $v_2.SetAttribute(2, this.$8_0 ? 0 : this.$N_0);
     };
};
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(OverridePromoAnimation, "sp.ui.tileview.js");
```

Comment: Did you see this another related question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108839/customize-promoted-links-tiles-view-in-sharepoint-2013/109130#109130 ?

Comment: Yeah...that's the one I linked as answer. I'm asking on how I'm supposed to edit the function. It doesn't clarify on how he changed the pixels.

Comment: Sorry about that, missed the link when it was wrapped on a word :) I did this once with a bit longer workaround, which however made the further customizing easier. I used SPJSTiles (http://spjsblog.com/2013/11/13/sharepoint-2013-style-tiles/), which includes a .css-file that can be easily customized. The spjsblog includes several posts about SPJSTiles, so I'd recommend going through them before implementing anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try to see if that workaround can be fully implemented since I don't have full permission for the site im editing. I'm still curious on how the user would edit that line if anyone can explain.

Comment: I just want to add that SPJSTiles can be implemented in the end. Thanks for that. I had to use v1.2.4 for Sharepoint 2016 since v1.2.5 caused an error. I am wondering if you're able to modify the animation easily? I'm trying to copy what this site (http://www.wavetec.com/solutions/customer-experience-solutions/) did for tiles' animation.

Comment: That seems like a plain programmatical question. I'd suggest to compose a question to stackoverflow about it, but give it a shot of your own at first!